# Adding default filtering on datatables server side pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to implement server side paging on a table and I always want to filter by a few set values.
Here is my datatables implementation code.

```
$("#FailedLoginLogTable").dataTable({
    "serverSide" : true,
    "processing" : true,
    "ajax" : "serverSideProcessingFailedLogin.php",
    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push( {name: "PageName", value: "Login"} );
    }
});
```

What I want to be doing is always limiting the results to where the column PageName = "Login".
if I comment out the fnServerParams section I get the full 26,300 results. But if I put it back in I get an error "Undefined is not a function" on

```
aoData.push( {name: "PageName", value: "Login"} );
```

Any idea why I am getting this error and how to filter the table by that column? Also, this isn't a column that is actually displayed if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fnServerParams` is a 1.9 feature and judging by the initialisation syntax, you're using 1.10

Comment: Strange. I saw no mention of it being taken out. Is there any alternative for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Actually you might be right, I think you _can_ still use fnServerParams, but according to the API, you can use [ajax.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data)

Comment: @markpsmith thanks! That allowed me to pass custom data to the server. I had to do a bit more to actually make it to where it put the values I sent into the WHERE clause but I was able to get it working.